# Break on all errors in edebug

Tags: error-handling, edebug, backtrace

How can I make Emacs break on an error, even if the error is being handled somewhere?

In my current scenario, the setup of a major mode is modifying the buffer and I want to find out why (and then fix it). I made a buffer read-only, ran `edebug-defun` on the major mode function and set `debug-on-error` to `t`, but running the major mode function still proceeds until it aborts with a “Buffer is read-only” error. How do I get it to break on error, so that I know where it is raised and can examine the environment? Or at the very least how do I get a backtrace?

Comment: You can try to temporary clear `debug-ignored-errors`, it contains a list of error symbols and regexp:s for which the debugger shouldn't start.

Comment: @Lindydancer Indeed, thanks. I found that in the docstring of `debug-on-error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting edebug options doesn't actually help here. Errors that are listed in [`debug-ignored-errors`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html#index-debug_002dignored_002derrors) are ignored *even while executing under Edebug*. This isn't mentioned in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Trapping-Errors.html#Trapping-Errors) (as of Emacs 24.5) but it is mentioned in the docstring of `debug-on-error` (for which `edebug-on-error` is just a proxy). (I don't understand why `debug-ignored-errors` has any influence on Edebug: it only makes sense to me as errors for which the debugger should not trigger during normal operation, not while debugging.)

So remove the problematic error from `debug-ignored-errors`:

```
(setq debug-ignored-errors (delq 'buffer-read-only debug-ignored-errors))
```

or just set `debug-ignored-errors` to `nil` while doing any debugging. This plus setting `debug-on-error` to `t` is enough to break on the error and get a backtrace.

Comment: The idea with the `debug-ignored-errors` variable is to let users have `debug-on-error` set to `t` at all times, and only enter the debugger when a real error occurs. Things like moving the point beyond the end of a buffer or a normal user error should not activate the debugger. However, a `buffer-read-only` error is borderline, in most cases it should not start the debugger but in some cases it should. The manual should really include this information, please report this as an error.